# Sizing WPF TextBox length to max number of characters allowed inside a report textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm

I know this can be a difficult-to-answer question but I've been asked to find an affordable solution and I don't know where to start looking at.
I've an existing report that's made via Word and has a replaceable text that would contain the data inserted as input via a WPF application.

Now since there's currently no length control on the WPF part, if I put more characters then the currently visible they'll be lost. I need a way to calculate based on a fixed font length the average number of characters allowed.

Not all the characters have the same width, for example the 'O' is larger then 'i'; my idea was to count the max number of O that can be inserted, the max number of i and do an average. From that value subtract a 15% in order to have a safe value. Is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, share your code and xaml

Comment: This question doesn't make sense at all. Do you want a method of calculation of size of the visible text in a TextBox ? Or do you need to set the MaxLength property ?

Comment: I need a method to calculate the size of a report textbox max character , so I can put it inside my WPF TextBox.I know how to set the Max Lenght

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [FormattedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.formattedtext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#examples). Listen to the `TextBox.TextChanged` event and measure the text once it has reached `TextBox.MaxLength`:

```
private void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var textBox = sender as TextBox;
  if (textBox.Text.Length == textBox.MaxLength)
  {
    // Create a formatted text string that has the max number of allowed characters.
    // and has therefore reached its maximum length
    FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
        textBox.Text,
        CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface("Verdana"),
        32,
        Brushes.Black);

   textBox.Text.Width = formattedText.Width;
}
```

Alternatively you could create a `FormattedText` composed of the known widest character (I think it's 'M' or 'W' most of the time) with `TextBox.MaxLength` number of characters, using your chosen 
typeface and then use `FormattedText.Width` to initialize the `TextBox.Width`.